# Get a tuple from Postgres as result using asterisk .* notation

Tags: postgresql

If I use the below code:

```sql
SELECT
    (player.id, player.firstname, player.lastname) AS player,
FROM
  player
```

I get this result:

```
+----------------+
| player         |
+----------------+
| (1,Bob,Smith)  |
+----------------+
| (2,John,Smith) |
+----------------+
```

I like it!

But I wanna use `player.*` instead of indicating each field.

I tried with:

```sql
SELECT
    (player.*) AS player,
FROM
  player
```

but the result is not like before: there are columns like:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 1  | Bob       | Smith    |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 2  | John      | Smith    |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Why? Is there a way to get a tuple with all the columns using `player.*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the table reference:

```
select player
from player;
```